# Is there a way to display table columns as rows?

Tags: css, html-table

I inherited some code that takes in a data source and renders that data as a HTML table as such:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Mrs</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Fonda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr</td>
    <td>William</td>
    <td>Shakespeare</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like the last table cell td content (Fonda, Shakespeare) to display as a new row beneath its original row. Is there a way to accomplish this via CSS?

Comment: It should not be difficult to do, we need more informations for that where does you data source comes from database, localstorage..if you just want to do it in frontend with javascript

Comment: Just fronted with CSS, ideally no Javascript

Comment: You will need javascript for that

Comment: Ok, vanilla Javascript only please

Comment: And what is stopping you from just altering the code that generates the table? (which IMHO would be by far the best solution)

Comment: You say, twice, "Ok, vanilla Javascript only please" as if this were a code-writing service and somebody is going to write the javascript _for_ you.  It would be an interesting problem to tackle for fun, but I agree with Peter B - just alter what is generating the table in the first place.

Comment: I don't believe I can alter the outputted HTML, the table is being generated from the Table input of the Observable Framework - https://observablehq.com/framework/inputs/table

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be done without javascript. but still I did my best. I hope you can benefit from it and improve it.

I know it might not be exactly what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/zj8r1amh/1/

```
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
  }
  td:last-child{border:0 none}
  td:last-child::after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    left: -113px;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top:34px
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Mrs</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td data-content="Fonda"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr</td>
    <td>William</td>
    <td data-content="Shakespeare"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! So close, I need the new row to be under their respective original row. Specifically, "Fonda" would be a new row under the row with cells "Mrs" and "Jane"

Comment: yes, i know:) i just gave it a try. But unfortunately, i think, it can not be done without any scripting. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, vanilla Javascript only please

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Note that I am note using classes or id (just tag name) you can be more pecific in targetting by looking at the class or the id for selecting table and row. The initial code has been edited to better answer the question

```js
const theTable = document.querySelector('table')
const theRows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr'))
let arrayOfRows = []


theRows.forEach(
    row=>{
        arrayOfRows.push(row)
    }
)

theTable.removeChild(theTable.firstElementChild)

for(let i=0; i<(theRows.length);i++){
    theTable.appendChild(arrayOfRows[i]) 
    let tr = document.querySelector('tr:last-child')   
    let node = tr.cloneNode(true) 
    theTable.appendChild(node)  
    let td = tr.querySelectorAll('td')
    let tdLastChild = tr.querySelector('td:last-child')
    td.forEach((td)=>{
        if(td!=tdLastChild){
            td.innerHTML=''
        }
    }) 
    // tr.style.display = 'flex' you can uncomment this line if you want the last td to be at the start of the line
    theTable.appendChild(arrayOfRows[i])   

    let trFirst = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(odd)') 
    trFirst.forEach((elem,idx)=>{
        let tdOddTr = trFirst[idx].querySelectorAll('td')  
        let tdOddTrLastElem = trFirst[idx].querySelector('td:last-child')  
        tdOddTr.forEach((tdElem)=>{
            if(tdElem===tdOddTrLastElem){
                tdElem.innerHTML=''
            }
        })   
    })    
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Mrs</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Fonda</td>
            <td>Actor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mr</td>
            <td>William</td>
            <td>Shakespeare</td>
            <td>poete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mr</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Wayne</td>
            <td>Actor</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: All this does is duplicating the last row...?

Comment: But isn't that what he wants duplicate thé last row?

Comment: No, he wants the third column of each row to instead display in its own separate row directly below the original row, so "Mrs" | "Jane" would be in row 1, "Fonda" would be in row 2, "Mr" | "William" would be in row 3, "Shakespeare" would be row 4

Comment: Ok I see that was not very clear.

Comment: Thank you for trying at least but @StephenP is correct and explained it well. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: @HBCondo thks for your words will try to update my answer later

Comment: @HBCondo I just updated my code with one quick simple way of doing it, i hope I properly understood this time . The last cells of each initial rows will be always on a new below row  compared to where it was before ( and just below its initial place)

Comment: If you want the last td cells to be at the beginning of the line below just uncomment the commented line of code. Also, if your table have th you will need to remoe it and add it after code treatment